# How to change the Facebook Messenger website plugin's Z-index

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've tried bunch of things, but I just can't seem to be able to change **Facebook's Messenger plugin** on my website to actually hide behind my cookie info.

My website is just plain HTML/CSS/Javascript, so I'm not using any extra plugins nor anything. When I inspect the element, Messenger's iframe has a `z-index: 2147483645`. And however I try to aim at it, I'm not able to change that value.

Recently I did a work-around, where I put my cookie notice on an even higher z-index, which works, but now Google crawled my page and put that cookie notice text right into my website description (even though I have a meta description tag) on Google results, which also isn't a result I'm aiming for here.

Has anyone managed to tackle this issue so far?

Edit:
Here's the facebook SDK code and my current cookie CSS settings..

```css
.cookie-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #2f3640;
  color: #f5f6fa;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  transition: 400ms;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 16px rgba(47, 54, 64, 0.404);
}

.cookie-container.active {
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 3000000000;
}

.cookie-btn {
    background: #2196f3;
    border: 0;
    color: #f5f6fa;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v9.0'
      });
    };
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;
      js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/hr_HR/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  }, 3000);
</script>

<!-- Your Chat Plugin code -->
<div class="fb-customerchat" attribution=setup_tool page_id="118677220048285" theme_color="#2196f3" logged_in_greeting="Pozdrav! Kako Vam mogu pomoći?" logged_out_greeting="Pozdrav! Kako Vam mogu pomoći?">
</div>


<div class="cookie-container">
  <p>
    Here's the cookie text with the agree button.
  </p>

  <button class="cookie-btn">
        Agree.
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, please go read [ask] and [mre]. Without a proper code example (and in a case like this, probably _also_ a live example, the chat plugin can not easily be tested without the proper config & setup), there is rather little we can say about problems like this.

Comment: _“I put my cookie notice on an even higher z-index, which works, but now Google crawled my page and put that cookie notice text right into my website description”_ - and that is supposed to be a result of _just_ a changed z-index? Anyway, some popular cookie banner plugins I came across fix _that_ issue by wrappering their output into `<!--googleoff: all-->` … `<!--googleon: all-->` comments, a technique explained here, https://support.google.com/gsa/answer/6329153?hl=en

Comment: @CBroe  I'm sorry, It's my first time asking a question here, I'll give those two links a thorough read and edit the question. I wasn't really sure which code to even show here, since Facebook SDK uses a script code on the website which creates the <iframe> afterwards, so manipulating the z-index on cookie notice was the only thing I thought of for now. The Google link you've linked is a perfectly solution for this for now. But I'll expand my question in case someone tries to search for it as I did.